# MSIX Core not working, MSIX package not installing

Tags: msix

I have installed `MSIX Core` on Windows 7 (supposedly to support MSIX packages). I double-click a MSIX package, but all I get is a message: `Windows cannot find msixmgr.exe. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.`

Then I open `regedit.exe` and go to `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\MSIX` to see what is going on as I double-click the file. Seems like this line is being executed: `"C:\Program Files\msixmgr\msixmgr.exe" -AddPackage "%1"`. Now I go to `C:\Program Files\msixmgr` and execute this line manually like this `msixmgr.exe -AddPackage "C:\mypackage.msix"`. A new command window opens, lots of `msixmgr.exe` help text runs by (really quickly) as if I used command-line incorrectly and then the new command window shuts down... nothing happened.

Installing MSIX package on Windows 7 does not work. What's the problem and how do I make it work?